# recursive itemgetter for python

Tags: python, recursion

Is there a recursive `itemgetter` in python. Let's say you have an object like

```
d = {'a': (1,2,3), 'b': {1: (5,6)}}
```

and I wanted to get the first element of the tuple from `d['a']`? As far as I can tell `itemgetter` will only do one level, i.e. get me `a` or `b` or both.

Is there some clever way of combining `itertools` with `itemgetter` to produce the desired result.

So basically what I want to be able to call is

```
from operator import itemgetter
d = {'a': (1,2), 'b': (4, (5,))}
itemgetter({'a': 0})(d) --> 1
itemgetter({'b': 0})(d) --> 4
itemgetter({'b': {1: 0}})(d) --> 5

d = {'a': {'b': (1,2,3)}}
itemgetter({'a': {'b': 2}})(d) --> 3
```

Comment: ok, so there is this (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jmespath) which does what I want, but is not part of the standard library

Comment: I don't know if it is clever or not, but `a1 = lambda d: itemgetter(1)(itemgetter('a')(d))` will do as requested, i.e. `a1(d)` will "get the first element of the tuple from `d['a']`".

Answer (score 10):

I don't like 'clever' ways. Obvious is better.

You can very easily write a getter that iterates along a list of subscripts:

```
def getter(x, *args):
    for k in args:
        x = x[k]
    return x

>>> d = {'a': (1,2,3), 'b': {1: (5,6)}}
>>> getter(d, 'a', 0)
1
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit... except when it isn't.  It's all full of... well, it's basically tradeoffs all the way down.  And yes, you can write that yourself.  But you can do so for tons of the syntactic sugar in core Python.  Decorators?